# Fastest way to create list from map object

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have some code:

```
map_ret = map(lambda x: x*x, Array)
```

Where `Array` is some numpy array with float numbers.

`map_ret` is a map object.

I want to get list from `map_ret`.

```
result = list(map_ret)
```

But when my array contains more when 1000000 numbers, it becomes very slow.

How the faster way to get values from map object?

Comment: I would not use `map` with `numpy.array` objects. `numpy` is already heavily vectorized, so I would just stay within that library. In this case for example you could say `map_ret = x*x` and let `numpy` do its thing.

Comment: Do **not** use `map` with `numpy.ndarray` objects. That will always be slower than regular python operations on lists or vectorized operations on `numpy.ndarray`s

Comment: Okay) So, if I want to do something (not only x*x, maybe other function on every element in numpy array) what I should use to do it faster? And if I want to do something like map not with numpy array, but with pandas dataframe, which way the fastest?

Comment: @Иван you probably want a vectorized version of your function. For analytical functions, you have your back covered by NumPy.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply your function to the input itself, thus completely bypassing `map()`. On my machine, this approach is approx. 2 orders of magnitude faster than `map()` for inputs of size `1_000_000`. Still, if you really need a list as output, you could use `.tolist()` to the resulting `np.ndarray()` and this is still approx. 1 order of magnitude faster then with `map()`.

```
import numpy as np


arr = np.arange(1000000).astype(float)


def my_func(x):
    return x * x


%timeit list(map(my_func, arr))
# 203 ms ± 3.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit my_func(arr)
# 1.6 ms ± 24.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit my_func(arr).tolist()
# 33.8 ms ± 471 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

Just to comment on "not using `map()`" on NumPy's arrays. If the input is not a NumPy array, but a list, e.g.:

```
list_ = [float(x) for x in range(1000000)]


%timeit list(map(my_func, list_))                                                                                                                                               
# 114 ms ± 1.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit my_func(np.array(list_)).tolist()                                                                                                                                       
# 64.4 ms ± 382 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The `map()` approach is definitely slower on NumPy's arrays than on lists, and eventually going through NumPy back and forth is still approx. twice as fast as `map()` directly on lists. 
This is why you received some comments against the use of `map()` on NumPy objects, since NumPy typically offers faster alternative to the typical `map()` use case.

Comment: Is it faster to use `list(map(my_func, list_))` or `[*map(my_func, list_)]`?

Comment: I guess the second option, but if so, not by much. I suppose you can try that yourself, so that you know better for your use case.